# How much memory is available for executing applications on Tablets (SDK 3.1)?

Tags: android, caching, memory

How much memory does an Android tablet allocate for application execution? As I know, Android applications use 16MB memory for their execution, how much memory is used when I execute an application on a Tablet(in SDK 3.1).

Does a device device give more memory for execution if it is available, because normally a tablet has more memory than a mobile device.

Also, I want know is whether **cache & data base memory is a part of that 16Mb memory** allocated by a device for the application. And how I can use cache memory for my application so that my application memory & performance are increased.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to know how much memory gives by android tablet for application execution.

Write an app for your tablet that calls `getMemoryClass()` on `ActivityManager` to find out the per-application heap for that device.

> Also I want know is cache & data base memory is a part of that 16Mb memory which is given by device for application.

Neither cache nor "data base" is held in memory. They are held in on-board flash storage, treated as a disk.

Comment: Hi CommonsWare, I am very very thanks for this great full information & I accept this answer. Now I am clear about internal memory and know that it is vary for device to device but lower limit is 16MB. Thanks For clearing cache & DB memory confusion.  Thanks Ones again. But if you know any link for use of cache in application then I am very thanks for this help also.

Comment: @AmolWadekar: Cache storage is typically used for holding things you download off the Internet, but can always download again in the future if need be.

Comment: Yes you right , But I want to use cache for consume view so that next time I don't need to reload it so that my performance is increased. Or What I do I store my data in cache & from that I recreate view, which is best way for me because my UI is very heavy due Tab. Thanks.